# Why use AddWithValue + Parameters["@somevar"].Value instead of just using AddWithValue? (MySql + C#)

Tags: c#, mysql

In the sample code at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html, there is the code(do each time : `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` in iteration):

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)";
    cmd.Prepare();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One");

    for (int i=1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value = i;
        cmd.Parameters["@text"].Value = "A string value";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Why is it not instead(do 1 time: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after iteration):

```
 try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)";
        cmd.Prepare();
        for (int i=1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", i);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One");
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I *think* Yosef is asking why use `cmd.Parameters["@number"].Value` inside the block instead of `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", i);`.  At least, I made an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is incorrect; the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is actually inside the loop.

This executes the query 1,000 times with different parameters, without re-creating the command.